# How to delete from multiple tables ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My code below is only deleting one record with same ID from the second table (`OrderDetail`). So, I want to rewrite my code in a correct way to delete all records with the same `OrderID` from second table (`OrderDetail`) when a record in `Order` table is deleted.

For instance if I delete `orderID = 1` from `Order` table, then the corresponding rows in the `OrderDetail` table should also be deleted.

`Order` table:

| OrderID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joan |
| 2 | Mary |

`OrderDetail` table:

| ID | OrderID | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Chair |
| 2 | 1 | Table |
| 3 | 1 | Plate |
| 4 | 2 | Table |

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] ICRUDModel<Order> value)
{
    Order order = _context.Order.Where(c => c.OrderID == (int)value.key).FirstOrDefault();

    OrderDetail order2 = _context.OrderDetail.Where(c => c.OrderID == (int)value.key).FirstOrDefault();

    _context.Order.Remove(order);
    _context.OrderDetailDetail.Remove(order2);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json(order);
}
```

Expected result

| OrderID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Mary |

`OrderDetail` table:

| ID | OrderID | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | Table |

Comment: Is it Entity Framework? Add tag. Which version? Look at [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete).

Answer (score 2):

You are only selecting the first record for OrderDetail. To select multiple, you need to select a list.

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] ICRUDModel<Order> value)
    {
        Order order = _context.Order.Where(c => c.OrderID == (int)value.key).FirstOrDefault();
        List<OrderDetail> order2 = _context.OrderDetail.Where(c => c.OrderID == (int)value.key).ToList();
        _context.Order.Remove(order);
        _context.OrderDetailDetail.RemoveRange(order2);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(order);
    }
```

Comment: It;s showing an error message: DbSet<OrderDetail> does not contain a defination for RemoveAll  and no accessible extension method RemoveAll accepting a first argument of typeDbSet<OrderDetail>

Comment: sorry it should be RemoveRange not RemoveAll. I updated my answer

Comment: It works. thank you